# Spectral norm of matrices with complex eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, singular-values, matrix-norms

Suppose that $M$ is a square, invertible matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$ where the lambda's can possibly be complex. Suppose that $\lambda_{\max}(M)$ is complex valued. How is the spectral norm going be defined in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite its name, the spectral norm of a matrix has nothing to do with the spectrum of the matrix. It is the largest *singular value* of the matrix. Unless the matrix is normal, you really cannot infer the largest singular value from the largest-sized eigenvalue.

E.g. consider $M=\pmatrix{\lambda&m\\ 0&\lambda}$ for a fixed $\lambda$. As $\lambda$ is fixed, the spectrum of $M$ is fixed, but $\|M\|\to\infty$ when $|m|\to\infty$.